# Entity Framework - Filtering rows with where() after include

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

If I have two objects or models as below:

```
   class School
    {
        ICollection<Student> students { get; set; }
    }

    class Student
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        School school { get; set; }
        bool Deleted { get; set; }
    }
```

Howcome when trying to get a school with only students that are not deleted doesn't work properly using the where clause?

```
var school = DatabaseContext.Schools
             .Include(x => x.Students)
             .Where(y => !y.Deleted).FirstOrDefault();
```

Shouldn't the where clause filter the students that are not deleted? Using where clause inside the include is not allowed too without using any third party libs.

Comment: "*Shouldn't the where clause filter the students that are not deleted* - the answer is it shouldn't do anything,  this wouldn't compile

Comment: @MichaelRandall the code isn't written very well since it only is an example/preview of my question, if we are talking about compiling that specific code

Comment: @RicardoPeres You are aware global query filders are a ef CORE feature and not in ef? No? Ah, too bad.

Comment: Aren't you missing the School property in the Student class?

Comment: @RicardoPeres Indeed thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go the other way, that is, select not deleted students and from them, project the schools:

```
var school = DatabaseContext.Students
                 .Where(s => !s.Deleted)
                 .Select(s => s.School)
                 .Distinct()
                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

This depends on a `School` property on the `Student` class, which is not present in your model, probably was forgotten.

Comment: How can you do it using IQueryable()? By removing firstordefault?

Comment: Don’t understand your question. My solution only works if you can query on students, that is, either if you expose a Students property or if you query using Set<Student>.

Comment: Will `Iqueryable<school> school = DatabaseContext.Students.Where(s => !s.Deleted).Select(s => s.School).Distinct();` work the same as your solution?

Comment: I think so, give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do to get desired result

```
var result = mydbcontext.Schools
                        .Include(d => d.students)
                        .Where(d => d.Id == 1) //the where clause filters only Schools
                        .Select(x=>new School
                        {
                            Id=x.Id,
                            students =x.students.Where(s=>!s.Deleted).ToList()
                        })
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .ToList();
```

Answer (score -2):

It does work, but you will need third party libraries - Filtered includes are NOT supported by EntityFramework and i think EF Core (thoug hthere they are iirc on the todo list).

The where clause can filter, but it can only filter out full objects top level, then the includes expand to sub elements.

What you want is include filtered or global query filters (filter out all students that are deleted unless I tell you not to).

https://entityframework-classic.net/ does that (free, a fork of ef)